# inject multiple services in controller mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, autofac, service-layer

Refactored my MVC application using entity framework as ORM and Autofac as DiContainter.

I run into the next "problem.
I have a controller where i do crud operations for a object that has lots of complex properties.

here I show a simplified example that has nothing to do with project.

```
public class Car  
{
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public int Doors { get; set; }
       public double Miles { get; set; }
       .....
       public Brand Brand { get; set; }
       public Engine Engine { get; set; }
       public FuelType FuelType {get;set;}

}

public class Brand 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }

    .....

}// Same for Engine, FuelType,....
```

for all these Objects I have services for CRUD actions

for objects with no complex properties i inject 1 service into my controller like

```
public class BrandController : Controller
{

    readonly IBrandService brandService;
    public KwaliteitController(IBrandService  _BrandService)
    {
        brandService = _BrandService;
    }
   //here comes actionresults for CRUD operations and etcetera...
 }
```

This works fine and looks clean for my.
Now the problem is for my CarController I also need all the names
"or other properties" for Fueltype, Brand, Engine,....

I can retrieve these values and Id's from there service but than i have to inject them all into my controller like

```
     public class CarController : Controller
{
    readonly ICarService carService;
    readonly IBrandService brandService;
    readonly IFuelTypeService fuelTypeService;
    readonly IEngineService engineService;
    public KwaliteitController(ICarService _CarService IBrandService  _BrandService,.....)
    {
        carService = _CarService;
        brandService = _BrandService;
        ....
    }
 }
```

In reality I have objects with more than 10 property's like this so i wouldt have to implement more than X services into my controller.
That looks to me like a serious overkill.
is there a way I can accomplish this without having to use all my services for 1 controller.

Comment: to Create a new Car

Comment: Classic sign of too many responsibilities. (SRP violation) review your design.

Comment: You should make use of generics in your service class(es), which will allow you to have to inject far fewer services, perhaps only just one. I have an example of something like this on my blog if you're interested: https://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/

Comment: Thej are Directly acting against a datasource. "Database" & csv files